# How to add --proxy-header using Selenium webdriver in PHP?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, proxy, php-curl

Im using Selenium by WebDriver in PHP script.

As selenium browser I have Firefox configurated on my docker container.

I need to add proxy header with some values to set proxy settings according to my expexctations same like I will do it using cURL like this:
`curl --proxy-header "X-Header-Value: VALUE"`

How to do it using selenium webdriver?

Note: its not just normal headers but proxy headers, adding it even manually in developer tools not works, but cURL version works great.